# Unable to use media query to specifically target my desktop

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to specifically target my desktop resolution using media query CSS which is 1366 x 768. Therefore i used this method.

```
@media (max-width: 1367px)
```

This desktop media query CSS actually works.

Unfortunately, it clashes with my media query CSS for my S4 and iPad which caused them not to be working. As shown below is my media query for my S4 and iPad

S4

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 440px)
```

iPad

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)
```

Apart from the method i tried above to perfect my CSS, is there any way i can specifically target the desktop resolution of mine which is 1366x768?

Comment: i've updated the question. sorry for the in-clarity.

Comment: use `min-width` instead `min-width:1365px`

Comment: sorry to say min-width doesn't work though.

Comment: You can't just use physical dimensions to determine what type of device it is.  You can only use them to determine the dimensions of the device/viewport, not determine whether or not the device has a mouse vs uses touch input.

Comment: currently, my current objective is trying to deduce a media query is specifically for my desktop resolution.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media (max-width: 1367px) and (min-width: 1365px)
```

Your max-width rule includes everything less wide than 1376px, so you should set a minimum.

Don't forget, these measurements refer to the browser window, and not the actual screen, so they may not be correct for your purposes.

For example, my desktop is at 1600 x 1200.
At full screen, my Firefox window, as it would be referenced by css, is 1583px wide. Not 1600px.

Comment: Also don't forget the order in which you specify your queries, if they overlap, matters. [See CSS Tricks for more info](http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/)

Comment: Typo on my part. Thanks for finding it.

Comment: Is your browser fullscreen or windowed? Can you type some js into your console? Try running this, what number does it give you? `alert(window.innerWidth)`

Comment: sorry. I'm not very well-verse in js though.

Comment: Is your browser full screen? Are there borders on the left or right of the browser window?

Answer (score 0):

Use more specific queries for your iPad and S4:

iPad

CSS

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  /* Styles */
}
```

Smartphone (S4)

CSS

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 440px) {
  /* Styles */
}
```

Comment: I believe this wont change anything though :/

Answer (score 0):

Start with the largest screen devices and update the rules as the resolution drops:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1367px){ ... }
@media screen and (max-width: 1366px) and (min-width:1024px){ ... }
@media screen and (min-width: 1023px) and (max-width:768px){ ... }
```

and so on.

If you want to make use of cascading, keep in mind that the last rules will inherit the styles from the rules declared before them:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1023px){...}
@media screen and (max-width:768px){...} ->
```

In this case, the screens < `768px` will inherit the rules from the previous declaration also.